# If cell value is 0 then delete column, Excel VBA - deletes all columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete columns if a certain cell in that column is "0" - I'm looping through all worksheets. I've tried different variations and it all ends up with different results - either nothing is deleted or everything is deleted.

Whole code:

```
Sub Finalize()
Dim finalform As Worksheet
Dim deletename As String
Dim finalworkbook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range
Dim columnloop As Range
Dim finalarray As Variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set finalform = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).ActiveSheet

finalarray = Array(finalform.Range("D3").Value, finalform.Range("D4").Value, finalform.Range("D5").Value _
, finalform.Range("D6").Value, finalform.Range("D7").Value, finalform.Range("D8").Value, finalform.Range("D9").Value _
, finalform.Range("D10").Value, finalform.Range("D11").Value, finalform.Range("D12").Value, finalform.Range("D13").Value _
, finalform.Range("D14").Value, finalform.Range("D15").Value)

On Error Resume Next
For a = 3 To 20

If Range("B" & a).Value <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open finalform.Range("B" & a).Value
    Set finalworkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

        'Find, replace, remove
        For Each ws In finalworkbook.Worksheets

            'Copy paste values
            If Not IsInArray(ws.Name, finalarray) Then
                Set copyrange = ws.Cells
                copyrange.Copy
                copyrange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Next ws

        For Each ws In finalworkbook.Worksheets
            'Delete sheets
            For b = 3 To 15
                deletename = finalform.Range("D" & b).Value
                If deletename <> "" Then
                    finalworkbook.Worksheets(deletename).Delete
                End If
            Next b

            With ws
                myChar = Chr(10)
                'Enter space
                .UsedRange.Replace What:="~~", Replacement:=myChar, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False

                For c = .UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                    cName = Split(Cells(, c).Address, "$")(1)
                    nom = .Range(cName & "8").Value
                    If nom = 0 Then
                        .Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
                    End If
                Next c
            End With
        Next ws

        finalworkbook.Save
        finalworkbook.Close
End If
Next a

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If nom = "0" Then` . If a cell is blank, `nom = 0` will also be `True` (not only when there is an actual zero in a cell), so your column will be deleted.

Comment: Also just an FYI a range of values is an array. Your long array can be shortened to `finalarray = finalform.Range("D3:D15").Value`

Comment: Are you trying to delete the column if the 8th row is "0"? I guess you are trying to test if the cell at 8th row is not used? If so, use `IsEmpty(range)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I wanted to delete the column if the row had a value "0" so I added the quotation marks in like all of you suggested. I figured out the bigger problem, I was referencing the wrong row - things like this always make me feel like an idiot but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is how VBA interprets the =0 operation. Here is a quick list. You most likely want to use IsEmpty() as ZygD noted.

```
IsEmpty(cell.Value) 'Returns true if the cell is empty, or false if it is filled with 0.

cell.Value = 0 'Returns true if the cell is empty and if it is filled with 0, false otherwise.

IsNumeric(cell.Value) 'Returns true if the cell is empty, or if it is filled with any number, false otherwise.
```

Comment: I wanted to delete the column if the row had a value "0" so I added the quotation marks in like all of you suggested. I figured out the bigger problem, I was referencing the wrong row - things like this always make me feel like an idiot but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping through all worksheets, you can even use `vbNullString`instead of 0 or "", as this runs faster.